# Asking a question about a potential tablet purchase (without getting yelled at)

Tags: support, site-recommendation, superuser

I want to ask a question about a potential purchase of an unbranded Windows tablet.

Where is the best place I can ask such a question?

I am considering posting this question to Super User, but I don't want to get yelled at for being off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Product recommendations are off-topic on any SE site.

It may fly in some chat rooms, but never as a question.

Comment: Good tip about the chat rooms, I wouldn't have thought of it. One point: some product recommendations are [on-topic on some sites](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation), given that they keep the rules (very specific requirements etc.).

Comment: @gbrlrz017 if this answer answers your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Shokhet Very specific, yes. But also no technology, which becomes out-of-date more quickly than books, etc.

Comment: If I understand the OP's question, it wouldn't be on-topic *anywhere*. Tech product recommendations are taken as on-topic on some sites I use, eg http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation+technology