# Provide an ellipsis after a long name instead of truncating it

Tags: feature-request, design, display-names, user-card

I changed my name on Meta Stack Exchange earlier today[.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2741998#2741998) I used 24 of the 30 allowed characters:

> Mooseman is eating pizza

However, now on [questions I have asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244638/202832), and [answers I posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244484/202832) or [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244726/202832), it shows my name as

> Mooseman is eating pizz

According to one source, '[pizz'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pizz) is a shortened version of '[pizzicato](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pizzicato)', which is

> a note or passage played by plucking strings

...but that's besides the point. Since 30 characters are allowed, and fewer than that are guaranteed to be visible...

#### I propose that the name `div` gets `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to provide an ellipsis after its truncated version.

Comment: So change your name... easy fix.

Comment: Not sure that would be an improvement in your case: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cx3uJ.png

Comment: @Oded Sure it will be, pi is more tasty than pizz :P

Comment: What about: *Mooseman's eating pizza* ? (that suggested, I couldn't hazard a guess at what size pizza you ordered, given this question is 2 days old... Perhaps just a full name change to "Mooseman's ready to pop")

Comment: @James what is that `'` doing there?

Comment: @James I have no objections to `Mooseman's eating pizza`, but I can't change my name on MSE until next month because of the 30-day waiting period.

Comment: @MichaelT It's replicating a `space` and an `i`, as in `is`.

Answer (score 11):

It actually wouldn't require any JavaScript. They could easily fix that with CSS:

```css
.user-info .user-details {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Personally I think it makes more sense to indicate that the name has been truncated, rather than just truncating and letting people wonder.

Comment: Now just need someone to test this on Safari to make sure it doesn't burn down your house.

Comment: @Shog Now I am afraid to test it... Anyway, thanks for warning :D And, assuming my house is SE, ain't you afraid  that it will blow up?

Comment: @Shog9 [Seems to work fine.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kukym.png)

Comment: @animuson This would be perfect; it just needs to be implemented.