# Are command prompt questions for Stack Overflow or Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, superuser

Are command prompt questions for Stack Overflow or Super User? I have no idea, they're both programming right?

The question in question is specifically about diagnosing internet connectivity issues, even more specifically about blank results for "ipconfig".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Super User

Super User for sure. ipconfig in itself isn't really programming, and your question regards diagnosing an issue with **your computer**, not code.

Comment: Shell scripting questions would go on [SO] though.

Comment: Unrelated... @Mooseman - your username is quite *unfortunately* cut off at the moment..

Comment: @James Oh yes... I have [a question about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244729/202832).

Comment: @DavidZ Really? I see plenty of shell scripting questions on [SU] (both windows and unix). Nobody ever seems to flag them as off topic or migrate them to [SO] ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I guess I have been less active on Super User recently, so maybe that has changed and I don't know. Or perhaps some questions are simply being overlooked because of the site's volume. But my impression was that shell scripting questions which count as programming should generally go to [SO] whereas those that are just ordinary, non-programming command prompt tasks (which I didn't mean to include in my first comment) would go on [SU].